# Pandas assign series to new column to multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, series

So I create a dataframe with MultiIndex

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'C1': ['x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'z', 'z'],
    'C2': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'],
    'C3': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]})
df.set_index(['C1', 'C2'], inplace=True)
```

And I get the following dataframe

```
       C3
C1 C2    
x  a   10
   b   11
y  a   12
   b   13
z  a   14
   b   15
```

I also have a series that has same index of `C2`:

```
series = pd.Series([100], index=['a'])
```

I would like to assign this series to a new column, `C4`, only to the 'x' first index. It works if I use `.assign`, but it returns a copy:

```
df.loc['x'].assign(C4=series)
```

and I obtain

```
    C3     C4
C2           
a   10  100.0
b   11    NaN
```

but I fail to assign it to the original data

```
df.loc['x'] = df.loc['x'].assign(C4=series)
```

yields

```
         C3
C1 C2      
x  a    NaN
   b    NaN
```

I get same result if I use assignment like this:

```
df.loc['x', 'C4'] = series
```

But it yields NaN.

```
         C3  C4
C1 C2          
x  a    NaN NaN
   b    NaN NaN
y  a   12.0 NaN
   b   13.0 NaN
z  a   14.0 NaN
   b   15.0 NaN
```

How can I assign in this way?

Comment: Can't you modify your Series to have MultiIndex? (`series.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([('x',), series.index])`) If that's possible, `df['C4'] = series` should work fine.

Comment: Yes, I can. Thanks for your insightful answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to assign this series to a new column, C4, only to the
>   'x' first index.

One way is to map your series from a level of your index. The key method is [`pd.Index.get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html). Then overwrite to `NaN` where a mapping is not required.

```
f['C4'] = df.index.get_level_values(1).map(series.get)
df.loc[df.index.get_level_values(0) != 'x', 'C4'] = np.nan

print(df)

       C3     C4
C1 C2           
x  a   10  100.0
   b   11    NaN
y  a   12    NaN
   b   13    NaN
z  a   14    NaN
   b   15    NaN
```

Alternatively, you can use `numpy.where`:

```
df['C4'] = np.where(df.index.get_level_values(0) == 'x',
                    df.index.get_level_values(1).map(series.get),
                    np.nan)
```

Comment: I actually prefer the `np.where` solution! Thank you

Answer (score 6):

You can go for `pd.IndexSlice` i.e

```
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice['x',series.index.tolist()],'C4']  = series.values

       C3     C4
C1 C2           
x  a   10  100.0
   b   11    NaN
y  a   12    NaN
   b   13    NaN
z  a   14    NaN
   b   15    NaN
```

Comment: @MathKid not sure what you meant, been 4 years since last answerd. If you have issues, raise a new question, stating this answer was not helpful with much deeper context.

Comment: Apologies, the answer actually does work correctly, even if the index label 'a' in `series` is not the first one in the list. I'm deleting my earlier comment

Comment: Instead of `pd.IndexSlice`, you can also just use a tuple. The `tolist()` bit is also superfluous, so you can just do `df.loc[('x', series.index), 'C4']  = series.values`.